# Water Under the Bridge

Tags: expressions

When someone tells you that it is "just water under the bridge", what does it mean when they say "But sometimes there is not any water under the bridge"?

Comment: The point about the metaphor *water under the bridge* is that once the water has passed by you will never see the same water again. There is no point in worrying about something that is over, as it is like *water (which has passed) under the bridge*.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I can sleep well now. Again, thanks for your response.~Demi~

Answer (score 4):

As @WS2 has alluded to in comments ***[Water Under the bridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/water-under-the-bridge)***
is an idiom meaning

> **problems that someone has had in the past that they do not worry about
>   because they happened a long time ago and cannot now be changed**:
> *Yes, we did have our disagreements but that's water under the bridge now.*

However,

> sometimes there is not any water under the bridge

is not a generally known/used idiom. One can infer that it means sometimes problems cannot be relegated to the past, as no water has flowed under the bridge.